# setting axis scale in matplotlib contour plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, contour

I'm generating a contour plot in matplotlib based on output from an FEM program which gives nodal coordinates and their corresponding state parameters as follows:

`x = [x1,x2,x3,...,xn]`
`y = [y1,y2,y3,...,yn]`
`z = [z1,z2,z3,...,zn]`

Where `z` is a list.

The contour plot is generated as follows

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as ml

#paste data extraction routine here to generate list for x, y and z

xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),len(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(y))
zi = ml.griddata(x,y,z,xi,yi, interp = 'linear')

plt.figure()
contourplot = plt.contourf(xi,yi,zi, cmap=plt.cm.bone,
                  origin='lower')
cbar = plt.colorbar(contourplot)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

The contour plot I'm getting depends on the second to last line `plt.axis('equal')`

If I include the line I get this:

[image]

If I don't include the line I get this:

[image]

The figure depicts deformation in a soil layer and I'd like to make sure that it plots to scale, and that I can control the resulting size of the image.

The first figure is to scale (i.e the axes are in the same scale) but its not taking up the entire figure as can be seen.

The second figure is not to scale, but it takes up the whole figure.

I'd like to make sure that I get a proper to-scale image. Can I control the axes in this manner? Thanks

Comment: I think you are looking for `plt.axis('scaled')`. Otherwise, setting the x and y limits explicitly should remove the extra whitespace in your first example.

Comment: That did it. Why don't you post your comment as an answer. I think it does the job

Comment: Yeah, it does the job but I agree with @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest that it would be cleaner to act on the axis object explicitly rather than implicitely via `plt`. I think you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use

```
plt.gca().set_aspect("equal")
```

instead of `plt.axis('equal')`. The result would look like

[image]

You may then also play with the figure size and the margins, e.g.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))
# ...
plt.tight_layout()
```

would result in

[image]

Comment: It looks like the codes "plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))" does not fit the original codes since here you use "figure" not "contour".

Comment: Is there any way that the contour size can be arbitrarily chosen?