# Python - setting arbitrary contour xy-ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I am reading the following discussion:
[setting axis scale in matplotlib contour plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48208222/setting-axis-scale-in-matplotlib-contour-plot)

From the discussion above, to get arbitrary ratio, we could use

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))
# ...
plt.tight_layout()
```

However, this setting is for `figure` not for `contourf`.

I used the above codes in my codes

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import math

rm = pd.read_excel("test_3d.xlsx", header = None)

# find min values of noise
rec = np.shape(rm)

# grid
X = np.arange(1,rec[1]+1,1)
Y = np.arange(1,rec[0]+1,1)
x , y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

# plots
plt.clf() 
con = plt.contourf(x,y,rm, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title('2457MHz')
plt.show()
```

The result I got is

[image]

The ratio of bottom plot is what I want; however, I use `plt.figure(figsize=(8,2))`, which is not for `contourf`. Therefore, I did not get the correct result.

Is there any way that I can plot arbitrary ratio for `contourf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the `figsize`, use [`Axes.set_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html) to change the aspect ratio of the contour plot's `Axes`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contourf(x, y, rm, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_aspect(0.25)
```

[image: contourf with 0.25 aspect]

If you prefer to stick with the `plt` syntax, access the `Axes` using [`plt.gca`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.gca.html):

```py
plt.contourf(x, y, rm, cmap='viridis')
plt.gca().set_aspect(0.25)
```